# Casting int to float results in illegal instruction

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded-linux

I'm using a MINI2440 board (S3C2440 CPU), running Linux.

I have this working :

```
double a=168.168;
printf("\nsqrt(%f)=%f\n", a, sqrt(a));
```

But I have this resulting in "Illegal instruction" :

```
float a = 0.0;
int b = 1;
a = (float)b;
```

I can't cast an int to a float ..

I tried to add / remove -msoft_float as well as -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED options, but it does not change anything ..

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `a = b;` and rely on the compiler doing the right thing (*many* / *some* / *a few* casts in C are just plain wrong).

Comment: Could be a code generation bug. Can you post the assembly you get by compiling that code snippet, just in case?

Comment: Is this a compilation error or a running error?

Comment: i think you are using a wrong compiler, which compile your code to the asm you board doesn't recognize.

Comment: or, it's more probable, that you use a compiler that generates hardware floating point instructions.

Comment: Try your first `sqrt` example with `-fno-builtin` or with `double a=168.8+printf("");`; I guess it will also fail.

Comment: The board has an ARM926 core.  Listed as having the FPU unit as *optional*.  Safe to assume it is *none* in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working ...

I missed to specify -march=armv4t and -mtune=arm920t options.

Now works perfectly, thanks.